# My SQL.Как вывести данные из смежной таблицы? Связь многое ко многим

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста!

Решила изучить SQL, дошла до вывода данных из таблиц со связью многое ко многим и застряла.

Допустим :

Таблица 1 **films**

---

### ID   |  name

1    | Начало

2    | Бэтмен

Таблица 2 **style**

---

### ID   | style

1    | боевик

2    | триллер

3    | детектив

Таблица 3 **fs**

---

### f_id    | s_id

1       | 2

1       | 3

2       | 1

2       | 2

Как вывести данные, чтобы в результирующей таблице было

Начало - Триллер

Начало - Детектив

Бэтмен - Боевик

Как создавала таблицы :

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  -- ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- name VARCHAR (20) );

CREATE TABLE style (
  -- ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- style VARCHAR (30) ); 

CREATE TABLE fs ( 
  -- f_id INT,
  -- s_id INT,
  -- PRIMARY KEY (f_id,s_id),
  -- FOREIGN KEY (f_id) REFERENCES films (ID),
  -- FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES style (ID));
```

Пыталась найти информацию в интернете, на YouTube, получилось вывести только так :

---

### f_id | name

1    | Начало

1    | Начало

2    | Бэтмен

2    | Бэтмен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, style FROM films 
    INNER JOIN fs ON films.id = fs.f_id 
    INNER JOIN style ON style.id = fs.s_id
```